# WPF C#: Rearrange items in datagrid via drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, drag-and-drop, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid, which source is CollectionView. I need to drag and drop items between groups.

Is there any way to implement it? Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879863/wpf-datagrid-drag-row-on-icollectionview-which-bind-to-collection might be a start to help u implement drag